# Node.js - express проблема с парсингом body

Tags: node.js, express, postman

почему-то express не парсит body:

```
var express = require('express'); 
        
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
        
var app = express();
        
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
        
app.use(bodyParser.json())
         
var port = 443;
         
app.post('/post/data', function(req, res) {
 console.log('receiving data...');
 console.log('req is ',req);
 console.log('req.body is ',req.body);
 res.sendStatus(200) 
});
         
app.listen(port); 
console.log('Server started! At http://localhost:' + port);
```

При отправке запроса пробовал указывать заголовок Content-Type, но это тоже не дало результата. Разница при использовании bodyParser лишь в том, что тело приходит как undefined или как {}. Ниже прилагаю полный запрос

И как я его отправляю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Грешил на POSTMAN, но и с другими утилитами такая же проблема. При этом всём абсолютно такой же код пару дней назад всё как надо парсил, может я что-то упускаю?

Comment: На вашем скриншоте написано `application/json`, но строчка `OK` это **не** JSON. Попробуйте отправить `{"OK":true}` например.

Comment: Эм, а вашем pastebin вообще `'content-length': '0'` — т.е. вы ничего не отправили.

Comment: @AlexeyTen да, поменял сейчас скрин в вопросе, вот собственно что я из постмэна отправляю, пробовал и через curl, и через другие сервисы, тож самое.

Comment: Т.е. и с локального хоста так, и если с другой машины отправлять.

Comment: Query params это не body. Они будут в [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query)

Comment: Хотите body отправляйте body (4 таб на вашем скришноте рядом с Headers)

Comment: @AlexeyTen тфу ты, проглядел :) Спасибо большое :)